# CakePHP not showing flash() messages?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, notifications

I am writing a CakePHP app but it doesn't seem to be showing flash() messages on any of the pages.
I am using `$this->Session->setFlash();` to set flash() messages and using `$this->Session->flash()` in my default template, as well as `$this->Session->flash('auth')` on the login and registration pages but they don't show the validation errors etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your views & layouts, you're looking for the session *helper*, not the session component that you're trying to use. In controllers/components, you use the session component and reference it as `$this->Session`. In your layouts and views, you use the session helper and reference it simply as `$session`. e.g. `$session->flash();`

More about the [session helper](http://book.cakephp.org/view/568/flash) can be found in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, you can use both with the 1.3 release, but the problem was that I forgot to echo the flash() to the screen.
That link showed me that I was supposed to do that.

Comment: Correct, $this->Session in the Component is used to call Session component, while $this->Session in View is calling Session helper.

Comment: Fair enough. You didn't mention a version and most of my work is still in 1.2 so I naturally gravitate in that direction. :-)